# Difficulty producing a simple scatter plot from csv file in python: x and y axis labeling

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I find it difficult to produce a simple scatter plot from csv file in python. I'm new to python and not sure how I'm supposed to label my x and y axises

My data has several columns: Country, 2002, 2007, 2012, 10 Year Net
Under country, there is a list of countries. Under 2002, 2007 and 2012 are net migration figures corresponding to those years. 10 Year Net has the 10 year net migration for years 2002-2012.

My code is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df  = pd.read_csv("../input/UNdata_Export_20170112_044235144.csv")
df.plot()  # plots all columns against index
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y') # scatter plot
df.plot(kind='density')  # estimate density function
# df.plot(kind='hist')  # histogram
```

When I run it I get the following errors:

```
KeyError: 'x'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'x'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-95582c0a0754> in <module>()
      4 df  = pd.read_csv("../input/UNdata_Export_20170112_044235144.csv")
      5 df.plot()  # plots all columns against index
----> 6 df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y') # scatter plot
      7 df.plot(kind='density')  # estimate density function
      8 # df.plot(kind='hist')  # histogram

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx,
```

How do I assign x and y values OR where do I go from here? I'm just trying to do a few simple graphics. Thanks! - robbie

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe has the columns named `Country, 2002, 2007, 2012, 10 Year Net` then there is no column `"x"` or `"y"` to be plotted, thus the key error.

You need to use the column names that you have, e.g.

```
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='2002',y='2007')
```

Just as an example, since I don't know if it makes sense to plot those columns, not knowing exactly the purpose of the plot.